# Playing audio, program crashing

Tags: vb.net

For some reason when i try to play the variable wordlist, the program crashes. I don't understand why.

I have added to the variable via "WordList.Add" and am trying to play (WordList(1))

I've tried troubleshooting to no success.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    While loopstart = 1
        If txtEnter.Text = arrWords(word) Then                        'If the text entered into the textbox is equal to the array word
            MsgBox("You got the correct answer " & word & "/10")      'A msgBox will appear telling them they got it right and the point will be added to the total.
            word = word + 1                                           'If word is correct, it'll go to the next word in the list
            txtEnter.Clear()                                          'Clears the textbox
        Else
            MsgBox("This is incorrect, try again")                    'Tells the user they failed and the user will have to reattempt untill correct
            txtEnter.Clear()                                          'Clears the textbox
        End If
        Exit While                                                    'Exits out of the loop
    End While

End Sub

Private Sub BtnPlay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlay.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(WordList(1))

End Sub

Private Sub Fm1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    arrWords(1) = "A"
    arrWords(2) = "Any"
    arrWords(3) = "Ask"
    arrWords(4) = "Come"
    arrWords(5) = "Go"                  'An array of words being used(Dimed up top)
    arrWords(6) = "He"
    arrWords(7) = "No"
    arrWords(8) = "Once"
    arrWords(9) = "The"
    arrWords(10) = "You"

    word = 1
    loopstart = 1       'Loop used in btnCheck

    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\A.wav", 1)
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\Any.wav", 2)
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\Ask.wav", 3)
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\Come.wav", 4)
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\Go.wav", 5)
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\He.wav", 6)        'Dictionary of words(Dimed up top) *Doesn't work
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\No.wav", 7)
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\Once.wav", 8)
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\The.wav", 9)
    WordList.Add("E:\Scintillating spelling simulator\Audio Files\Year 1\You.wav", 10)



    loopstart2 = 1
    song = 1
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How does it crash? is there an exception? if so, on what line and what exception? what do you mean with >I've tried troubleshooting to no success ? have you stepped through the code with a debugger? where do you declare and initialize `arrWords` and `WordList`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you initialize the `Dictionary properly`:

```
Private WordList As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
```